# How to return a specific value from an object in firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I ran across a problem while create some backend things for an app I'm making. I store a value referencing a link to an image in a firestore document. In order to access this image, I need to fetch this link, and only this link if possible. If not, It would be great to get any suggestions on how to tackle this problem in other ways - thanks!

```
    async function ListImageData()
{
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", "userUID2", "images"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.get['image:']);
      });
}
```

Image of outputted Data -
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Document databases generally should be designed so that a single query (document) has all the information you need. This results in lots of duplicated data, and that is fine.

> Rule 1: Favor embedding unless there is a compelling reason not to.
> -[MongoDB Schema Design Best Practices](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-schema-design-best-practices/)

That being said, the image link should be available from fetching/getting a single document like [the documentation shows how](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) to do:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: how could I go about isolating the link by itself? I have a few ideas about regex, but that seems overly complicated. Ill add an image to my question that shows what the console output is.

Comment: `doc.data().image`